# Binary heap deletion algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

In a binary heap ,in order to delete an element:
We delete the node at the root - this is the node with highest priority.

After deleting there is a hole at the root, which has to be filled, and to make sure that the hole appears at the last node, we render the deletion to an insertion in top-down direction. We insert in the hole the last element that has been inserted.

Then, sliding the "hole" down and moving up the smaller of the childrens of the "hole", and repeat this until the hole gets to the bottom. The hole may appear anywhere at the bottom.

My questions are:

**Q1**: Is there's another way to delete an element without extracting the minimum(I mean the last leaf node that we place in the hole).

**Q2**: If I delete the element from the list or the tree, and reconstruct the binary heap again,from the list after removing the element ,I'll have a tree ordered from to down according to priority but it'll be in different order at the tree level ,than the original tree before deletion,is this correct or it must be in same order at depth and level.

e.g if the original binary heap is `L = [6,10,12,15,17,21,23,20,19,34,18]`

If i delete the root element by the binary heap heap algorithm it should be

```
L = [10,15,12,18,17,21,23,20,19,34]
```

So my attempt is, if I delete 6 then I'll have the list `L = [10,12,15,17,21,23,20,19,34,18]`, now I reconstruct the heap by inserting every element in the list one by one so the binary heap list will be `L = [10,12,15,17,18,23,20,19,34,21]`, is that correct or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your ultimate question is yes, it is correct. After all, all you're suggesting is to eliminate the first (i.e., the minimal) value and then use the heap-insert algorithm to rebuild the heap from the remaining elements.

It's a *really* bad idea, though, if you're concerned with efficiency. On a heap with $n$ elements, the standard *deleteMin* algorithm will take $\Theta(\log n)$ time, since you only have to restore the heap along one branch of the tree. In your proposed method, it will take $\Theta(n)$ steps to completely rebuild the heap, if for no other reason than you have to reinsert all the $n-1$ remaining elements.

Comment: sure you are totally correct it's bad idea ,but what was confusing me and was searching for convincing is an example to answer the thought which is  (all what binary heap concerning is to have a tree ordered in depth from top to down ,and not about tree level from left to right all what matter is if the parent higher in priority but not about which children is right and which is left).so you answer is that what i understand is correct.